# The preamble doesn't appear in my cv

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to write my cv using Latex (moderncv). I am using the following code, for which there is no error but the name, email ... don't appear.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{10}{10}\mdseries\upshape}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} 

\firstname{S}
\familyname{\textsc{S}} 
\title{\large{Deta} 
\extrainfo{23,se,cel}} 
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{document}
```

Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if you are using a template and where you got it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make these information appear on the CV, you need command `\makecvtitle`. You messed up with the curly braces in the `\extrainfo` part.

The correct code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}


\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{10cm}}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{10}{10}\mdseries\upshape}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} 

\firstname{John}
\familyname{\textsc{Doe}} 
\title{\large{Deta}} 
\extrainfo{23,se,cel}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Éducation}
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{document}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Where should I put it ?

Comment: You should put it after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Part of the premable appears, and I get `Undefined control sequence. \makecvtitle`

Comment: @din: Weklcome to Tex sx!  `\maketitle` will be enough.

Comment: @Bernard Thx. I got a similar error: `Undefined control sequence. \section` and the part `extrainfo` doesn't appear.

Comment: See my new comments.